# Updating path for virtualenvwrapper 19.10

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

I'm installing virtualenvwrapper on my machine so that I can start managing environments in python more carefully. I have virtualenvwrapper.sh in its default location but following [this](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) guide I'm running into a problem after adding the lines to `~/.bashrc`. When I run `source ~/.bashrc` I get the message

`If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.`

I think what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507186/python-virtualenv-no-module-named-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader) guys did is what I need to do to fix it but I don't know what what changing the name to `python.bak` does. Also he says to use $PATH. I'm not sure if mine should be as long as it is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Also, the command python3 seems to run just fine. Not sure where I'd defined `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=` or what I'd set it to.

Thanks in advance for the help! I'm very new to all this which is probably already abundantly clear.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I needed to put

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3`

on the line just above

`source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`